# C++: do I need to free the pointer inside function?

Tags: c++, pointers

Do I need to free the `ptr`? If so, how?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printFromPtr(int *ptr);

int main()  
{   
  int a = 3;
  int numPrint = 10000;
  for (int i = 0; i < numPrint; i++)   
  {
    printFromPtr(&a);
  }   
}

void printFromPtr(int* ptr) 
{
  cout << *ptr << endl; 
}
```

Comment: omg. that's too quick and hard to choose the best answer.. thanks all!

Comment: Well answered already, so here is some reading on the [concept of Storage Duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No.

The function is receiving a pointer from the caller, and does not know how the memory being pointed at was allocated, so it has no business trying to free it. Only the caller knows how it was allocated, so only the caller knows how to free it.

In this example, the caller is passing a pointer to a local variable `a` that is not allocated dynamically, so there is nothing to free manually.  The variable will be gone when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to free any pointer as you are not doing any dynamic memory allocation here.

Answer (score 1):

when we are doing dynamic memory allocation then we need to free pointers.

[Read this for more info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

in your code you are passing pointer to local variable, so no need to free pointers.it will automatically remove(after reaching in out of scope.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) only for pointers obtained by [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). Beware of [dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) and of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Be very [afraid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And in C++ you should prefer [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) (and use standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) when convenient). And you generally don't use `malloc` and `free` in C++ (only in C). However many implementations of `new` are *internally* using `malloc`, etc...

Read also about the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), and about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), about [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), about [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), about [constructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) and [destructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_programming)), about [virtual method tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46991224/841108) question.

Answer (score 0):

No.You have not allocated dynamic memory & no need to free the ptr.In your code ptr  stores address of  variable reside in the stack not the heap.