# How to have a node structure that holds an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

I can't find anything online about making a linked list with individual nodes that hold arrays.

```
struct node{
    string list[]; 
    string var;
    node* next = NULL; 
    node* previous = NULL; 

}; 

void insertion(node*& start, string name, string words[]){
  node* temp = new node;
  temp->var = name;
  temp->list = words;

  if (!start) { 
    start = temp;
    return;
  } else { 
    node* tail = start;
    while(tail->next) {
      tail=tail->next;
    }
    tail->next = temp;
    temp->previous = tail;
 }
```

The code above gives me the error:

> web.cpp: In function ‘void insertion(variable*&, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string*)’:
>   web.cpp:18:16: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string*}’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string [0] {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string [0]}’
>        temp->list = words;

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a raw array. Arrays need to have a definite size and cannot be assigned directly.

Comment: @user0042 Raw arrays are more efficient and can be just as easy to use as vectors.

Comment: @Cppplus1 _"Raw arrays are more efficient"_ Can you elaborate please how so? At least for fixed size array a `std::array` should be used.

Comment: @Cpp plus 1: except that you can't assign raw arrays...

Comment: @user0042 Whether or not Vectors are as  efficient as arrays depends much on the compiler.

Comment: Maybe if you are using turbo c++. Any modern compiler the efficiency will be the same.

Comment: @Cppplus1 _"depends much on the compiler"_ Sorry to tell you, but that's just nonsense.

Comment: Would it be possible to use another linked list instead of an array? And if so how would that be possible?

Comment: @user0042 They can change in size. Whenever you change its size, a new array is created, which is inefficient. It is much better to create an array with the correct size to begin with.

Comment: ***Whenever you change its size, a new array is created*** That is not how vectors are implemented.

Comment: @drescherjm Then how do they change size?

Comment: They usually have grow algorithms. And only grow / shrink when a threshold is met.

Comment: @drescherjm But when the threshold is met, a new set of memory needs to be allocated.

Comment: Yes however that is at least as good as you would do it yourself with new / delete.

Comment: @drescherjm Only if you absolutely needed to change the size. Without using Vectors, you might find that you can initialize an array with a constant, large size.

Comment: If you don't need to change the size then use std::array.

Comment: @Cppplus1 Here's a [recommended read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-with-modern-c) if you are seriously interested to dive deeper into that topic.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `string list[]` is not allowed as a data member definition, since it is an incomplete type. So your code actually should give you an error already in the definition of `struct node`.

In addition to that issue, in C++, array types are not assignable (regardless of their size).
So even if you wrote:

```
struct node{
    string list[4];
    string var;
    node* next = NULL;
    node* previous = NULL;

};

int main(){

    node n1;
    node n2;

    n1.list = n2.list;  // error: array types are not assignable
}
```

you'd get an error indicating that array types cannot be assigned in the sense of `array1 = array2`.

If you used a `vector<string>`, in contrast, you could assign as well as letting your vector dynamically grow as needed.