# How to correctly deallocate class member?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, user-defined-functions, class-members

Should I use `delete` overload or `del()` function or something else to deallocate class member?

```cpp
class Field
{
private:
    size_t* square = new size_t[5];
public:
    void del()
    {
        delete[] square;
    }
    void operator delete (void* p)
    {
        delete[] reinterpret_cast<Field*>(p)->square;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Field f;

    delete &f; 
    //or
    f.del();
}
```

Comment: Neither. Please use a [destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor).

Comment: Don't use new or delete if you can avoid them. Use a `vector`

Comment: [Are there any valid use cases to use new and delete, raw pointers or c-style arrays with modern C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-raw-pointers-or-c-style-arr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for a destructor:

```
class Field
{
private:
    size_t* square = new size_t[5];
public:
    ~Field() { delete [] square; }
};
```

But learn the [Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and defer instead to a resource managing class:

```
class Field
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<size_t[]> square;
public:
    Field() : square(new size_t[5]) { }
};
```

Which has the benefits of having move semantics already do the right thing, copy semantics already being disabled, and the destructor already managing your resources.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use delete overload or del() function or something else to deallocate class member?

Neither.

Add a destructor and make sure to delete the memory in the destructor.

```
class Field
{
  private:
    size_t* square = new size_t[5];
  public:
    ~Field() { delete [] square; }
};
```

While at it, checkout the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and follow the rule.

Answer (score 1):

First: Don't override the delete operator; this rarely makes sense. "Cleaning" up dependent objects, if necessary, is done in the destructor.

So you'd write

```
class Field {
   ...
   virtual ~Field() { delete[] square; }
   ...
}
```

Note that deleting a field (explicitly or implicitly) will trigger the destructor.

Second, call `delete` only on objects that you have previously created with `new`. Don't  delete objects with automatic storage duration like you do with `Field f; delete &f`.

Third, avoid allocating objects with `new` if automatic storage duration is an option, too. So you'd overcome the complete issue if you wrote:

```
class Field
{
private:
    size_t square[5];
};

int main() {
    Field f;
}
```