# C++ How to read data file to struct or vectors and return struct or vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

I already did this in MATLAB and want to do it in C++. The file I want to read from looks similar to:

```
0,397   0,372   0,385   0,354   0,397   0,384
0,389   0,347   0,385   0,317   0,397   0,380
0,379   0,308   0,381   0,285   0,395   0,361
```

Since the data is represented like that I had to choose a way to store it. I made a Class called OrlData which should have a function that read the text file and put the data into a array or a struct like:

```
struct DATA
{
  float a[400];
  string line;
} orldata[1200];
```

This struct should work like a normal array, orldata[1].a[2] = 0,347 and so on. But while searching for a better solution I figured that it was bad practice to return an array and it would be better to use vectors. (But I havent really had the breakthrough with those so I continued with structs)

My code is as below and is actually working. This is not implemented in the Class OrlData and is in the main until now. It is loading the file into the struct orldata:

```
 struct DATA
 {
     float a[400];
     string line;

 } orldata[MAX];


int main()
{
   int counter = 0;
   int index = 0;
   std::string Filename = "orl/orl_data.txt";
   std::ifstream input(Filename);
   std::string line;

   while (std::getline(input, line)) {
      counter++;
      orldata[counter].line = line;

   }
   for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
       std::istringstream iss(orldata[i].line);
       for (std::string s; iss >> s; ) {
           orldata[i].a[index] = strtof((s).c_str(), 0);
           index++;
       }
       index = 0;
   }
   std::cout << orldata[2].a[5];

   return 0;
  }
```

But when I tried to put this code into a function which should return the struct it crashed:

```
DATA ORLData::create_orl_data() {
   DATA orldata[1200];
   ....
   return orldata[1200];
}

...
int main(){
   ORLData orltemp;
   ORLData::DATA orlstruct = orltemp.create_orl_data();
   ....
}
```

Until now I understood that it's bad practice to return struct arrays like this. And I learned that it's better to use vectors but I havent figured out how to actually use them as matrices.

So my problem can be summed to: I want to read from a text file that looks like the above and then load them into an array like array[0].a[2] which should store all the data. How can I do this?

Please ask if you want me to elaborate on the issues I have.

Comment: Why are you using raw arrays, when other parts of your code already use `std::vector`?

Comment: Good question. Its because it was something I tried and didnt succed with.

Comment: May I recommend you reading this: [Are there any valid use cases to use new and delete, raw pointers or c-style arrays with modern C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-raw-pointers-or-c-style-arr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATA ORLData::create_orl_data() {
   DATA orldata[1200];
   ....
   return orldata[1200];
}
```

is wrong on couple of accounts.

1. It can return only one element of the array.
2. The valid ranges for the index of `orldata` is 0-1199. `return orldata[1200]` accesses the array using an out of bounds index, and causes undefined behavior. In your case, that results in a crash.

Change that function to return a `std::vector<DATA>`.

```
std::vector<DATA> ORLData::create_orl_data() {
   std::vector<DATA> orldata;
   ....
   return orldata;
}
```

Comment: Hi :)

I changed the start of my function to:
std::vector<DATA> ORLData::create_orl_data() {
 std::vector<DATA> orldata;
and then it gave an error "Expression: vector subscript out of range" and I debugged it and figured the error came from "
 while (std::getline(input, line)) {
  counter++;
  orldata[counter].line = line;
Do you know why?

Comment: Use `Data data; data.line = line; orldata.push_back(data);`.