# C++ const double pointer

Tags: c++, constants, const-pointer

I want to make a constant double pointer points to a constant pointer points to a constant double. I started to make it  (of course I make a little search at books and I googled it) from scratch and think what the following three make:

```
const double* cp; //pointer to a constant double
double *const cp; //constant pointer
const double *const cp; //constant pointer to a constant double
```

I thought the next step is to write a constant double pointer

```
double **const cp;// double constant pointer
```

then I combine the last two statements and I write

```
const double *const cp = arr[0];
double **const cp1 = arr ;
```

where arr is a dynamically allocated double dimension array.
After that I tried to verify what I have done and I wrote the below statements expecting to produce error all of them.

```
**cp1 = 1;    // didn't produce error  
*cp1 = arr[4];    // didn't produce error
cp1 = new double*[5]; //produce error
```

So the thing is that I couldn't make what I described above , a constant double pointer points to a constant pointer points to a constant double. How can I make it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommended read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-raw-pointers-or-c-style-arr

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's only one `const` in

```
double **const cp1 = arr ;
//       ^^^^^
```

so I'm not sure why you're expecting the other two assignments to produce an error.

If you want it to be `const` on all levels, you need

```
const double *const *const cp1 = arr;
//                         ^ cp1 is ...
//                  ^ a const pointer to ...
//           ^ a const pointer to ...
// ^ a const double
```

Comment: Thank you so much, not only for the answer but for your explanation below your code with your comments. Even in books I didn't find an explanation like this only examples .

Comment: I would like to elevate this answer to holy status. This is a great explanation for begginers about how pointers should be read and I think it should be present in more places around communities like this.