# What is a legal definition of a pointer to a pointer to a const object?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854238/c-const-double-pointer) that a pointer `const int** z` is supposed to be read as

> Variable *z* is [a pointer to [a pointer to a `const int` object]].

In my humble opinion, this would mean if `z=&y` then `y` should be a pointer to a `const int` object. However, the following code also compiles:

```cpp
int x=0;
int const* y=&x;
const int** z=&y;
```

Why is an `int const*` object i.e. a `const` pointer to an `int` instead of a pointer to a `const int` acceptable to be the pointed object of `z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the const refers to. A const always refers to the element to the left of it - unless it is the leftmost element itself, in which it refers to the element to the right.

This means that
`int const *` is a pointer to a const int, not a const pointer to int as you think. To get that, you would have to write `int * const`

`int const *` and `const int *` are two ways of writing exactly the same: a pointer to a const int.

You get it right if you read declarations from *right* to *left*. If const is the leftmost element, add a "that is" before it when reading. Ex:

1. `const int *`: pointer to int that is const.
2. `int const *`: pointer to const int.
3. `int * const`: const pointer to int.
4. `const int * const`: const pointer to int that is const.
5. `int const * const`: const pointer to const int.

Note that 1/2 are the same, and 4/5 are the same. 1 and 4 are called "west const" since const is on the west/left side, while 2 and 5 are called "east const".

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, and I now understand that the * in ```int const*``` means pointer to a ```const int``` object while the * in ```int* const```  means a (```const```) pointer to an ```int```.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is an `int const`* object i.e. a `const` pointer to an `int`

No.

`int const *` and `const int *` are the same type.

People sometimes prefer writing `int const *` because it reads right-to-left as *"pointer to a const int"*, whereas `const int *` really reads as *"pointer to an int (which is const)"*.

A `const` pointer to an `int` is `int * const`.

Try it:

```
  int a = 42;
  const int * y = &a;
  int const * z = &a;

  *y = 24; // compile error assigning to const
  *z = 24; // compile error assigning to const

  int b = 0;
  y = &b;
  z = &b; // re-pointing non-const pointers is fine
  *z = 1; // still a compile error

  int * const x = &a;
  *x = 24; // fine, assigning via pointer to non-const
  x = &b;  // error reassigning a const pointer
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! I now realise where my mistake was and the fact that the two notations are the same~