# C - const qualifier discard when const void* is actually struct**

Tags: c, gcc, gcc11

Stuck on "cast discards 'const' qualifier"

I have a code:

```
int cmp_str_and_dirent(const void *key, const void *elem) {
   const char *name = key;
   const struct dirent *de = *(const struct dirent**)elem;
                              ^ Cast discards `const` qualifier
   return strcmp(name, de->d_name);
}

struct dirent **entries;
file_count = scandir(path, &entres, NULL, alphasort);

struct dirent *found = bsearch(name, entries, file_count,
                               sizeof(struct dirent*), cmp_str_and_dirent);
```

So the question is: How to properly do dereferencing from `const void *` if that pointer is actually pointer to a pointer to a structure?

compiler gcc 11.2.1, using `-std=gnu11`

Comment: It it was C++, I'd try something like `const struct dirent * const de = *(const struct dirent * const*)elem;`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854238/c-const-double-pointer

Comment: This compiles without a warning for me, with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, on Ubuntu 22.04 (gcc 11.3.0). Can you [edit] your question and show how you are invoking `gcc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although C allows type qualifiers such as `const` to be placed before type names so as to allow their usage to appear similar to storage classes such as `register`, this obscures their meaning when they are used in pointer declarations.  Although `register int *p` would declare a pointer with `register` storage class that identifies an `int`, the definition `const int *q` defines a non-const pointer to a `const int`.  Move `const` qualifiers after the type name, and recognize that their placement relative to asterisks is significant, and all will become clear.  I think what you want is to convert the pointer to a `(struct dirent const * const *)`, i.e. a pointer to a read-only pointer to a read-only object.

Comment: Thanks, `(struct dirent const * const *)` or `(const struct dirent * const *)` - both works.