# C++ program run perfectly on Linux but can't run on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, g++, codeblocks

I have this code which run perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. But when i build and run it via Codeblock on Windows. It's just CRASH. I don't know what i was wrong and how can i fix this problem. There are a lot of C++ program that i wrote which can run on Linux but CRASH on Windows like that.

[Crashed Pricture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bX3H.png)

Thanks you guys so much for the help!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int d = 1;

void topRight(int [999][999], int, int, int, int);
void bottomLeft(int [999][999], int, int, int, int);

void topRight(int a[999][999], int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  for (int i=x1;i<=x2;i++) a[y1][i]=d++;
  for (int j=y1+1;j<=y2;j++) a[j][x2]=d++;
  if (x2-x1>0 && y2-y1>0){
    y1++;
    x2--;
    bottomLeft(a,x1,y1,x2,y2);
  }
}

void bottomLeft(int a[999][999], int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    for (int i=x2;i>=x1;i--) a[y2][i]=d++;
    for (int j=y2-1;j>=y1;j--) a[j][x1]=d++;
    if (x2-x1>0 && y2-y1>0) {
        x1++;
    y2--;
        topRight(a,x1,y1,x2,y2);
    }
}

int main(void){
  int a[999][999],m,n,i,j;
  cout << "Insert n: ";
  cin >> n;
  cout << "Insert m: ";
  cin >> m;
  topRight(a,0,0,n-1,m-1);
  cout << "\nA spiral-shaped two-dimensional array whith size " << m << " x " << n << " is: \n\n";
  for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
      cout << a[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

I compiled on Ubuntu terminal with this command:

```
g++ program.cpp -o program
```

And ran it with this command:

```
./program
```

Comment: You should not declare `int [999][999]` as function parameters because it does not do what you think it does and you should not create large arrays such as `int a[999][999]` on the stack.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger.

Comment: Compile with -O3 -g on linux. It may crash then. Use the debugger to find out where.

Comment: Recommended read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-raw-pointers-or-c-style-arr

Comment: I suggest for the rest of your life to initialize all your variables and members. 0xC00000FD = stack overflow, which means your recursions are getting out of hand.

Comment: Just a guess, but you are allocating a million ints on the stack. That's 4mib. Probably too much for Windows (a quick search showed that the stack on win can be 1mib). Try to put that data onto the heap.

Comment: I.e. use an std:: vector

Comment: here are the stack sizes: https://cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt

Comment: Thanks you guys for the help. I'm going to try it tommorow <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare 999x999 matrix, with simple math:

```
999*999 = 998001
```

An integer holds 4 byte in memory, so

```
998001*4 = 3992004
```

Almost equals to 4*10^6 byte. When u declare a variable in your main function, it tries to take memory from the stack. In stack, you can not give such that memory. Thats why you are getting stackoverflow error.

Try to reduce the sizes of your matrice or declare this variable as global. But global variables also have limit.

Comment: I'll try it it. Thanks for your help

Comment: An integer is not **required** to be 4 bytes; it is required to be at least 16 bits wide. Many compilers these days **do** use 4-byte integers, but, again, that is not required; some don't.