# how to read different length of data into 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays

As the title, how could I read different length of data into 2d array?
And I know the upper limit of data length for each line.
like..

5 6 9 8 4

5 4 9 5 6 5

1 2 3

4 5

I want to input these data into each row of 2d array, but c++'s cin will skip the input which is '\n'

so the method below doesn't work

```
for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
{
 int ch=0;
 while( (cin >> ch)!='\n' )
 {   
  element[i][ch] = true;
 }
}
```

so, how could I fix this?
or, how could I distinguish '\n'? to let my "while" know that .
thx a lot.

Comment: Urgently recommended read: [Are there any valid use cases to use new and delete, raw pointers or c-style arrays with modern C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-raw-pointers-or-c-style-arr)

Comment: To catch up with line endings use `std::getline()`.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` so they don't have to be the same length?

Comment: Why are you using the numbers as array indexes?

Comment: Thx for your reply. The input in first line (5 6 9 8 4)means that point1 could approach point 5 6 9 8 4. Therefore, I wold like to choose element[0][5,6,9,8,4] = true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::getline()` to read a line into a string. Create a `std::stringstream` from that and then read each number into an array element.

```
std::string line;
int row = 0;
while(std::getline(cin, line)) {
    std::stringstream linein(line);
    int num;
    int col = 0;
    while (linein >> num) {
        element[row][col++] = num;
    }
    row++;
}
```