# Function throwing write access exception

Tags: c++, c, exception, access-violation

I was reading an article or post online found here: [Eli Bendersky's Website : Binary Representation of Big Numbers](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2003/07/04/interesting-problem-binary-representation-of-big-numbers) and came across a function so I decided to test it in my IDE. The function compiles & builds but when I run the code it wants to throw an exception : write access violation.

Here is the function:

```
/* Note: in and out may be the same string,
   it will still work OK
*/
void longdiv2(const char* in, char* out)
{
    int carry = 0;

    while (*in)
    {
        int numerator = *in++ - '0';
        numerator += carry;

        carry = (numerator % 2) == 0 ? 0 : 10;
        *out++ = '0' + (numerator / 2);
    }

    *out = '\0';
}
```

I use it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char* value = "12345";
    char* binResult = '\0';

    longdiv2( value, binResult );

    std::cout << *binResult << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char q;
    std::cin >> q;

    return 0;
}
```

The access violation is thrown on this line:

```
 *out++ = '0' + (numerator / 2);
```

The violation is stating that `out` was `nullptr`.

---

I'm running this on MS Visual Studio 2017 CE on an Intel Quad Core Extreme running Win7 Home Premium x64 - compiled and built as an x86 console application.

[*Note:*] I tagged this with both C & C++: I tagged it like this because the article mentioned that they written it for C, however I'm using the same function in C++.

Comment: already negative critics without explanation...

Comment: `char* binResult = '\0';` is effectively the same as writing `char* binResult = nullptr;`

Comment: note the downvoter. Just `char* binResult = '\0';` that is wrong wrong wrong

Comment: okay; I still tried it unitilized'

Comment: you have to pass a valid buffer to your function. Don't point on char or string literal BTW.

Comment: Yeah my "C" is a little rusty... It's been a while since I've worked with C strings...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Urgently recommended read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-raw-pointers-or-c-style-arr

Comment: Just take the compiler's warning(s) serious.

Comment: @user0042 I know about smart pointers: I was trying to test this function out; then I was going to re-write in a modern C++ fashion.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I'd ditch the c-style strings completely in preference of `std::string`.

Comment: @user0042 I normally use std::string over c-style strings. I was just trying to get this function to work first before I convert it into C++ using templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*out++` is accessing pointer which is not pointing to valid memory.  That's why you get access violation when de-referencing it, after having an illegal memory access. This would work

```
char binResult[10];
```

Here basically when you pass it to the function you would be passing the decayed `char*` and make changes to it.

Alternatively this will also do

```
binResult =(char*) malloc(10);
if( binResult == NULL){
  perror("Malloc Failed");
}
```

> In detail, the problem boils down to that the ***pointer was not
>   pointing to any buffer where you can store the results***. When you try
>   to access that, you were basically trying to write to some memory that
>   you don't even have permission to. (***Write access violation***). That's
>   why you get the error.

To be even more clear it shouldn't come as suprise when you set pointer value to `\0` and then try to access it. On the first iteration itself it causes the `nullptr` access, causing the error.

Full `C` code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void longdiv2(const char* in, char* out)
{
    int carry = 0;

    while (*in)
    {
        int numerator = *in++ - '0';
        numerator += carry;

        carry = (numerator % 2) == 0 ? 0 : 10;
        *out++ = '0' + (numerator / 2);
    }

    *out = '\0';
}


int main(void) {
    char* value = "12345";
    char binResult[10];

    longdiv2( value, binResult );

    printf("%s\n",binResult);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
06172
```

Code compiled using `gcc 6.3.0`: `gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`

A `C++` solution would be something like

```
/* Here in and out shouldn't point to same thing */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void longdiv2(std::string in, std::string& out)
{
    int carry = 0;

    for(auto x:in)
    {
        int numerator = x - '0';
        numerator += carry;

        carry = (numerator % 2) == 0 ? 0 : 10;
        out.push_back( '0' + (numerator / 2));
    }

}

int main(void) {
    std::string value = "12345";
    std::string binResult;

    longdiv2( value, binResult );

    std::cout<<binResult<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
char* binResult = '\0';
```

to:

```
char binResult[10] {};
```

Comment: (which should not even have compiled): no it's an integral value. Maybe a warning, but effectively sets the pointer to 0

Comment: Why do you think `char* binResult = '\0';` shouldn't compile? It's perfectly valid.

Comment: I already stated in my question that it "DOES" compile & "Builds"; it was throwing an exception at runtime. I know what the runtime exception is: my C is a little rusty and was having a hard time remembering what was causing it with `C` style strings over preferred `C++` `std::string`...