# Destructor for a List class in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, containers, singly-linked-list, object-lifetime

I'm new to C++ thus the question. I've a toy implementation of a Singly Linked List in C++.

```
template<typename T>
class List {
    template<typename U>
    struct Node {
        U data_;
        Node<U>* next_;

        Node() : data_(0), next_(nullptr) {}
        Node(U data) : data_(data), next_(nullptr) {}
    };

private:
    Node<T>* head_;
    std::size_t size_;

public:
    List() : head_{nullptr}, size_{0} {}

    void insert(const T& item) {
        Node<T>* p(new Node<T>(item));
        if (size_ == 0) {
            head_ = p;
        } else {
            p->next_ = head_;
            head_ = p;
        }
        size_++;
    }
    std::size_t getSize() {
        return size_;
    }

    ~List(){
    while(head_){
        Node<T> p = head_;
        delete(p);
        head_ = head_->next_;
    }
};
```

This code seems to work.  The problem though is that the objects allocated by `new` are never cleaned up, despite the `~List()` destructor. Can someone help me understand, how I can write a destructor for this class that cleans up all the allocated nodes ?

**Important remark:** I am aware that this can be done using smart pointers, but I want to understand the old school way of managing heap.

Comment: Try writing the destructor, and then ask questions about any problems you are having with it - no-one is going to write it for you.

Comment: A destructor for a class `T` is a member function of no arguments named `~T`.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over the nodes in the list? Then you basically know all you need to know.

Comment: @Incomputable I've edited the question to add my implementation of the destructor. Is that the way to do it or is there a better way.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've edited the question to add my implementation of the destructor. Is that the way to do it or is there a better way.

Comment: You can't delete before you dereference. Also p should be a pointer to a node.

Comment: @MelissaStewart, basically what drescherjm said. Copy the next then delete, then assign current to next. Also, after you made it work correctly, if you're interested in raising implementation quality I recommend coming to [CodeReview.se]. P.S. upvoted.

Comment: @Incomputable I'm new to C++, I vaguely understand what you're saying, but a line of code will really help.

Comment: @MelissaStewart Urgently recommended read: [Are there any valid use cases to use new and delete, raw pointers or c-style arrays with modern C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-raw-pointers-or-c-style-arr)

Comment: @MelissaStewart ***"... but I want to understand the old school way of managing heap. ..."*** There never was an _"old school way"_. RAII was existing from the beginning of the c++ language. If you want to learn c idioms, then go for c please.

Comment: @user0042 At the same time, blindly using tools like smart pointers and containers without understanding what's going on internally is not ideal either. Understanding pointers may not be the best thing to start with in general, but some people prefer to start from the technical foundations to get better understanding. And from some skill level onwards, you *need* to understand the low-level details to be able to program correctly.

Comment: Why is `Node` a template? Will a `List<SomeType>` ever contain nodes which store something else than `SomeType`?

Comment: @Angew Though that's nothing fitting well for the OP's intro _"I'm new to C++ ..."_

Comment: In general, you might be interested in our [list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: @NeilButterworth there is a destructor in the code. It just doesn't work as OP would have expected

Comment: @Christophe There is one _now_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while(head_){
    Node<T> p = head_; <-- change to pointer
    delete(p); <-- you can't delete this right now
    head_ = head_->next_;
}
```

`p` should be a pointer. You cannot delete `p` right away. You have to find the `next` node, and delete `p` later. Also use `delete p;` instead of `delete (p);` as follows:

```
~List() {
    while(head_) {
        Node<T> *p = head_;
        head_ = head_->next_;
        delete p;
    }
}
```

As noted in comments, `Node` does not need to be a template. You can simplify your class. `insert` can also be simplified because `head_` is initialized to `nullptr`, you can safely assign `p->next_ = head_;`

```
template<typename T> class List {
    struct Node {
        T data_;
        Node* next_;
        Node() : data_(0), next_(nullptr) {}
        Node(T data) : data_(data), next_(nullptr) {}
    };
    Node* head_;
    std::size_t size_;
public:
    List() : head_{ nullptr }, size_{ 0 } {}

    void insert(const T& item) {
        Node* p = new Node(item);
        p->next_ = head_;
        head_ = p;
        size_++;
    }

    std::size_t getSize() {
        return size_;
    }

    ~List() {
        while(head_) {
            Node *marked = head_;
            head_ = head_->next_;
            delete marked;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is that you have to figure out who is the *owner* of the object to decide who should delete it.

In relation to nodes, the List is the owner. So you should carefully develop all the methods in a way that once the List looses the ownership of the object, it makes sure that object is deleted or the ownership is taken over.

Obvious places when you want to free the memory is, first one you delete the list. Second, when you remove an element, for example pop it.

Lets look in both cases.

First delete the list. For that you need to write a destructor, which iterates over the list and deletes elements one by one. For that I refer to the answer of @barmak-shemiani.

For the case when you pop an element you can do following:

```
  T pop() {
    Node<T> *tmp = head_;
    if (head_ != nullptr) {
      head_ = head_->next_;
      T data = tmp->data_;
      delete tmp;
      return data;
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("Can't pop an empty list")
  }
```

Comment: The code you've posted won't even compile, and it's buggy.

Comment: @Angew what's buggy about it?

Comment: What will it return when `head_` is null when called? Either you expect it not to be, in which case the `if` is pointless, or you expect it could be, in which case you should handle it fully.