# Memory deallocation of temporary object c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, concatenation

I build a simple string class. 
I try to make the concatenation functions which one of them is `+` and the other `+=`.
When trying to implement `+=` I generate a `Str` object under that equals the 1st string and which size is `s.size()`. But then when I tried to append to it a new string `t` I need to free the old array `s` string and allocate new size for it. After the destructor of the temp Str object is called it stucks there when freeing the old space and I can't understand why. How can I deallocate the `Str` under the `+` member function?

```
class Str
{

public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef char* iterator;
    typedef const char* const_iterator;
    iterator begin(){ return p; }
    iterator end() { return p + std::strlen(p); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return p; }
    const_iterator end() const { return p + std::strlen(p); }

    size_type size() const { return data_length; }
    Str() {};


    Str(const Str& s): 
        p(new char[s.size() +1]), 
        data_length(s.size())
    {
        std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), p);
        p[data_length] = '\0';
    }

    Str(const char* cp) :
        p(new char[std::strlen(cp) + 1 ]), 
        data_length(std::strlen(cp))
    {
        std::copy(cp, cp+ std::strlen(cp) + 1,p);//copies also the '\0' char to the last place in p
    }


Str& operator=(Str& rhs)//assignment operator
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        uncreate();
        create(rhs.size());
        std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end() + 1, p);
        //p[rhs.size()] = '\0';
    }
    return *this;
}

Str& operator=(const char* cp)//assignment operator
{
    if (cp!= p)
    {
        uncreate();
        create(std::strlen(cp));
        std::copy(cp, cp+std::strlen(cp), p);
        p[data_length] = '\0';
    }
    return *this;
}




    Str& operator+=(const Str&);

    ~Str() 
    {
        delete[] p;//stucked here while returning from + member function
        data_length = 0;
    }

    const char* c_str() const;
    void copy(char* ,size_type);
private:
    char* p;
    size_type data_length = 0;

    const_iterator ci() const { return p; }

    void uncreate();
    void create(size_type);
};



Str operator+(const Str& s, const Str& t)
{
    Str r = s;
    r += t;
    return r;   

}


inline Str& Str::operator+=(const Str &s)
{
    //trying to allocate new space for this object 

    std::copy(s.begin(),s.end(),p+this->size());
    p[data_length] = '\0';
    return *this;
}

void Str::create(Str::size_type n)
{
    p = new char[n + 1];
    data_length = n;
}

void Str::uncreate()
{
    delete[] p;//to check that p is allocated right
    data_length = 0;
}
```

The `main` for example:

```
int main()
{

    Str s1 = "hello"; 
    Str s2 = "worly";
    Str s3 = s1 + s2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You just [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-raw-pointers-or-c-style-arr)! Use `std::string` instread.

Comment: I try to dealocate the `r` object? can I do that?

Comment: What is wrong with doing it in the destructor like you already are?

Comment: Show your code for Str::operator+= . All else you have in your question appears ok at first glance.

Comment: @Nitesh hello, now shown as previously

Comment: You just have a comment saying _trying to allocate_, but no code actually allocating anything. Your existing buffer at `p` is pretty much guaranteed not to be big enough for `this->size() + s.size()` characters, which is what you need.

Comment: @Useless hello, that is why I started this question. How can I allocate enough memory for `this` and `s` ?

Comment: @axcelenator as expected, the operator += does not allocate more memory for the characters being added. You need to allocate new memory to p for new size.

Comment: @axcelenator but in your question the problem you ask is about deallocation: "How can I deallocate the Str under the + member function?"

Comment: @Nitesh because the `+` function calls the `+=`  I don't know what is the wright place for the deallocation. Do I need just to do `delete[] p`?

Comment: If this is for production work, use std::string.  If this is an educational exercise, you should have exactly *one* call to strlen in your code - in the constructor from `const char*`, to initialize `datalen`.  Every other call should use `datalen` instead.  (That way, your string - like std::string - can contain embedded nul characters.)

Comment: @axcelenator : You don't need a deallocator.  The destructor of `r` in operator + will do the deallocation.  Of course, in `operator +=`, you need to 1.  allocate enough memory.  2. copy the initial portion from the old memory.  3.  copy the appended string from the rhs.  4. deallocate the old memory.  5. store the pointer in `this->p` (step 3 needs to come before step 4, in case someone does `s+=s`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want something like this:

```
inline Str& Str::operator+=(const Str &s)
{
    const int new_data_length = data_length + s.data_length;
    char * temp = new char[new_data_length + 1];
    memcpy(temp, p, data_length);
    memcpy(temp + data_length, s.p, s.data_length);

    delete [] p;
    p = temp;

    data_length = new_data_length;
    p[data_length] = 0;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o hello when returning from `+` operator the delete[] operator in the destructor stopps the program

Comment: You *must not* delete the old `p` until after you copied from `s.p` - they may be the same variable (`s += s;`)

Comment: @MartinBonner - Good catch, hadn't thought of that when I commented to replace p with temp, although I think the concept still applies, copy everything into `temp` and then once all the copying is done, delete `p` and then assign `temp` to `p`.  The extra copy back step is unnecessary.

Comment: You cannot `delete [] temp` after assigning it to `p`.

Comment: Thanks, commenters. Maybe, I shouldn't be posting at all, today :)