# How to return pointer to variable sized array C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am creating a function that accepts variable sized array and return squared array. But there seems a problem in the function declaration - I get error as `error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*'`. What is proper way to return pointer to variable size array?

```
#include <iostream>
    int *arrSqr(int *a[],int *b)
{
    for (int k=0;k!=*b;++k)
        *a[k] = (*a[k]) * (*a[k]);
    return a;

}

int main()
{
    int* variable_arr;
    int size=10;
    variable_arr = new int[size];
    for (int k=0; k<size; ++k)
        variable_arr[k] = k;
    int *v2=arrSqr(variable_arr,size);
    //display
    for (int k=0; k<size; ++k)
        std::cout<<(*v2)[k]<<"  ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this compile? You’re giving in `int*` to a function that expects `int*[]`. If you just gave the `int*` you could return the same pointer. Don’t know why it needs to be returned here anyway.

Comment: I know about returning vector, asking about arrays.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991224/are-there-any-valid-use-cases-to-use-new-and-delete-raw-pointers-or-c-style-arr

Comment: *"What is proper way to return pointer to variable size array?"* - Make `std::vector` do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass an int pointer for the array and an int for the size. And then your code simplifies because you don't have to dereference everywhere, you just use operator [].

```
#include <iostream>
int *arrSqr(int *a, int b) //<- here I changed the function signature to take int* and an int
{
    for (int k = 0; k != b; ++k) //<- you don't need to dereference the size
        a[k] = (a[k]) * (a[k]); //<- you can just use [] to index the array
    return a;

}

int main()
{
    int* variable_arr;
    int size = 10;
    variable_arr = new int[size];
    for (int k = 0; k<size; ++k)
        variable_arr[k] = k;
    int *v2 = arrSqr(variable_arr, size);
    //display
    for (int k = 0; k<size; ++k)
        std::cout << v2[k] << "  "; //<- same story when printing
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell why you don't need to dereference `a[k] = (a[k]) * (a[k])`? Aren't we accessing memory object of pointer?

Comment: Because `a[k]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(a+k)`, so you are still dereferencing it, but you don't need to do it twice. It's just how c arrays work, they are pointers and you add the index to them